# onkeypress event not work properly in Mozilla Firefox Web Browser

Tags: javascript

I have a html table with onkeypress event Like :

```
<tr onclick="RowOnClickEvent();" class="PikerBodyRowStyle" onkeypress="return Test(event);">
                                    <td class="PikerCellStyle" style="width:10px; text-align:left"> <input type="checkbox" value="@item.AccountHeadID" name="chkBox" /> </td>
                                    <td class="PikerCellStyle" style="width:150px; text-align:left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountCode)</td>
                                    <td class="PikerCellStyle" style="width:160px; text-align:left">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountHeadName)</td>
                                </tr>
```

And my JavaScript function like :

```
function Test(e) {
//        debugger;
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if (SelectedItemID > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "ChartsOfAccount")',
                    data: { id: SelectedItemID },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

its work good in Internet explorer but Mozilla Firefox not work.

Comment: xdazz i try onkeypress="return Test(event);" but still now i face same problem

Comment: I believe you're going to run into cross-browser issues when trying to put a key event on an element that typically doesn't respond to a key event, like a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
onkeypress="return Test(e);"
```

to

```
onkeypress="return Test(event);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give a javascript action to a tablerow. Instead you can use some button or link to create your action. You can also put it in td tag. javascript actions works there.